# Issue in installation of google chrome in fedora 14

Tags: google-chrome, installation

I am trying to install Google chrome stable version in my system fedora-14 32 bits.

But i got error every time related dependencies...

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.i386 0:34.0.1847.132-1 set to be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) for package: google-chrome-stable-34.0.1847.132-1.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.14.3) for package: google-chrome-stable-34.0.1847.132-1.i386
--> Processing Conflict: google-chrome-stable-34.0.1847.132-1.i386 conflicts libX11 < 1.4.99
--> Processing Conflict: google-chrome-stable-34.0.1847.132-1.i386 conflicts libX11 < 1.4.99
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: google-chrome-stable conflicts with libX11-1.3.4-3.fc14.i686
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-34.0.1847.132-1.i386 (google)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-34.0.1847.132-1.i386 (google)
           Requires: libnss3.so(NSS_3.14.3)
Error: google-chrome-stable conflicts with libX11-1.3.4-4.fc14.i686
```

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can try installing an older version of Chrome.
For instance, get this one
ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/sourceforge/c/ch/chromeostab/OS@TAB1/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.rpm
install it with packet manager so you can solve dependencies, and you're done.
It works.